# Get Mouse Clicked Position in Scaled Child relative to it's Parent? (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

I'm attempting to use a JavaFX `Pane` to hold various shapes that I create by pressing the mouse.

I have two nested `Pane`s that control the dropping & layout of all the shapes I generate.

- The `ListenerPane` is the foreground `Pane`, which serves solely to house all the mouse event callback functions. This `Pane` always stays in the same location & will always have the same scale.
- The `HolderPane` is the background `Pane`, which serves to store all the created shapes as children. This `Pane` is able to move around & scale according to the user's mouse actions. For easier visualization, I colored this `Pane` in the dark blue color and made it smaller than the `ListenerPane`, to see how it moves & scales. The actual size of the `HolderPane` doesn't matter, it solely serves to hold all the shapes.

All the created shapes are orange circles, and are generated upon a left-mouse button click. The `HolderPane` can move when the mouse is dragged while holding the right-mouse button. Additionally, one should be able to reset the position & scale of the `HolderPane` by clicking the right-mouse button while holding the `ALT` key.

SceneBuilder scene hierarchy:

[image]

Along with the following controller Java code & FXML file:

```
package com.mycompany.mre;

import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class PrimaryController 
{
    @FXML
    public Pane ListenerPane;
    @FXML
    public Pane HolderPane;
    
    public class pos
    {
        double x;
        double y;
        
        pos(double xValue, double yValue)
        {
            x = xValue;
            y = yValue;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
        }
    }

    public pos MousePressedPos = null;
    public pos HolderPaneMoveStartPos = null;
    
    public boolean LMBPressed = false;
    public boolean RMBPressed = false;
    public double Zoom = 1;
    
    @FXML
    public void OnMousePressed(MouseEvent event)
    {
        if (event.isPrimaryButtonDown() && !LMBPressed)
        {
            LMBPressed = true;
        }
        else if (event.isSecondaryButtonDown() && !RMBPressed)
        {
            // Remembering the holder pane starting pos...
            MousePressedPos = new pos(event.getX(), event.getY());
            HolderPaneMoveStartPos = new pos(HolderPane.getTranslateX(), HolderPane.getTranslateY());
            
            RMBPressed = true;
        }
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void OnMouseReleased(MouseEvent event)
    {
        if (LMBPressed)
        {
            // Dropping a shape...
            Circle circle = new Circle(10, Color.ORANGE);
            circle.setStrokeWidth(1);
            circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            
            // Calculating the shape dropping position...
            pos dropPos = new pos(event.getX() - HolderPane.getTranslateX(), 
                                  event.getY() - HolderPane.getTranslateY());
            
            circle.setTranslateX(dropPos.x);
            circle.setTranslateY(dropPos.y);
            
            System.out.println("Dropped a shape at " + dropPos.toString() + "...");
            
            HolderPane.getChildren().add(circle);
           
            LMBPressed = false;
        }
        else if (RMBPressed)
        {
            // Resetting the holder pane starting pos...
            MousePressedPos = null;
            HolderPaneMoveStartPos = null;
            
            // Checking if auto-zoom is triggered...
            if (event.isAltDown())
            {
                HolderPane.setTranslateX(0);
                HolderPane.setTranslateY(0);
                HolderPane.setScaleX(1);
                HolderPane.setScaleY(1);
                Zoom = 1;
            }
            
            RMBPressed = false;
        }
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void OnMouseDragged(MouseEvent event)
    {
        if (RMBPressed)
        {
            // Moving the holder pane...
            HolderPane.setTranslateX(HolderPaneMoveStartPos.x + (event.getX() - MousePressedPos.x));
            HolderPane.setTranslateY(HolderPaneMoveStartPos.y + (event.getY() - MousePressedPos.y));
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void OnScroll(ScrollEvent event)
    {
        // Calculating new zoom...
        double[] zoomLimits = {0.5, 4};
        double zoomFactor = 1.5;
        
        if (event.getDeltaY() < 0)
            if ((Zoom / zoomFactor) <= zoomLimits[0])
                Zoom = zoomLimits[0];
            else
                Zoom /= zoomFactor;
        else
            if ((Zoom * zoomFactor) >= zoomLimits[1])
                Zoom = zoomLimits[1];
            else
                Zoom *= zoomFactor;
        
        // Scaling the holder pane...
        HolderPane.setScaleX(Zoom);
        HolderPane.setScaleY(Zoom);
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>


<Pane fx:id="ListenerPane" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" onMouseDragged="#OnMouseDragged" onMousePressed="#OnMousePressed" onMouseReleased="#OnMouseReleased" onScroll="#OnScroll" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.mycompany.mre.PrimaryController">
   <children>
      <Pane fx:id="HolderPane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="250.0" prefWidth="400.0" style="-fx-background-color: darkblue;" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

This setup allows me to create the shapes upon clicking the mouse & move them around as such:

[image]

The issue comes in when I scale the `HolderPane` by scrolling the mouse and calling the `setScaleX` & `setScaleY` functions, and try to drop more shapes. The shapes do not drop where my cursor is when I click the mouse:

[image]

I think this is happening because I'm getting the mouse location in the `OnMouseReleased` function by calling the `getX` and `getY` functions (marked in the code above with a `Calculating the shape dropping position...` comment). As far as I understand, those functions provide me with the mouse position relative to the source of the `MouseEvent` argument, which is always the `ListenerPane`, so the coordinates of the clicked coordinates in the `ListenerPane` do not carry over correctly to the `HolderPane`. I require some method of calculating the clicked position relative to `ListenerPane`'s child `HolderPane`.

Currently I'm simply subtracting the `HolderPane` translation position from the mouse position I acquired in `OnMouseReleased`, which only works when the `HolderPane` has a scale of 1.

The reason I have all my callback functions in the `ListenerPane` in the first place is because the `HolderPane` will move around when the user drags the mouse & scrolls, so they won't be able to click on the `HolderPane` if they move it too far. I wanted to allow the user to be able to click anywhere on the screen, not only on the `HolderPane`.

I also tried using the `getSceneX`/`getSceneY` and `getScreenX`/`getScreenY` functions instead of `getX`/`getY`, to no avail. It appears that this will require some math that I'm not familliar with.

What would be the correct way to approach this? Is there a formula for calculating a child node's relative position from a position relative to it's parent, while taking into account the scale of the child?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Off-topic: please use proper naming conventions when posting code publicly. This is very difficult to read for Java programmers.

Comment: The `Node` class has many built-in methods such as `localToScene`, `parentToLocal`, and so on to help with translating coordinates.

Comment: Thanks @Slaw, using the `parentToLocal` function appears to have worked here. You should post that as the solution to this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Node` class has many methods, such as `parentToLocal`, to convert coordinates to different spaces. Since your "listener pane" is a direct parent of the "holder pane", using `parentToLocal` should work for you. In general though, using `localToScene` followed by `sceneToLocal` should work for any two nodes in the same scene.

Here's a *proof-of-concept*, based on your code, using `parentToLocal`.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var holderPane = new Pane();
        holderPane.setBackground(Background.fill(Color.BLUE));
        holderPane.setMinSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        holderPane.setPrefSize(300, 175);

        var listenerPane = createListenerPane(holderPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(listenerPane, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Pane createListenerPane(Pane holderPane) {
        var listenerPane = new Pane(holderPane);

        var handler = new ListenerPaneMouseHandler(holderPane);
        listenerPane.setOnMousePressed(handler);
        listenerPane.setOnMouseDragged(handler);
        listenerPane.setOnMouseClicked(handler);

        listenerPane.setOnScroll(e -> {
            if (e.getDeltaY() != 0) {
                double factor = 1.5;

                double scale = holderPane.getScaleX();
                if (e.getDeltaY() < 0) {
                    scale /= factor;
                } else {
                    scale *= factor;
                }
                scale = Math.max(0.5, Math.min(4, scale)); // clamp scale to [0.5, 4]
                holderPane.setScaleX(scale);
                holderPane.setScaleY(scale);
            }
        });

        return listenerPane;
    }

    // Aggregate onPressed, onDragged, and onClicked handler
    private static class ListenerPaneMouseHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

        private final Pane holderPane;

        private double dragOriginX;
        private double dragOriginY;
        private boolean wasDragged;

        ListenerPaneMouseHandler(Pane holderPane) {
            this.holderPane = holderPane;
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            event.consume();
            if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
                handlePressed(event);
            } else if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
                handleDragged(event);
            } else if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED) {
                handleClicked(event);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("unsupported type: " + event.getEventType());
            }
        }

        private void handlePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            wasDragged = false;
            /*
             * Dragging 'holderPane' around does not require converting the
             * coordinates. Moving a non-transformed pane by 5 pixels and moving
             * a transformed pane by 5 pixels is the same thing.
             */
            dragOriginX = event.getX();
            dragOriginY = event.getY();
        }

        private void handleDragged(MouseEvent event) {
            wasDragged = true;

            double deltaX = event.getX() - dragOriginX;
            double deltaY = event.getY() - dragOriginY;
            dragOriginX += deltaX;
            dragOriginY += deltaY;

            holderPane.setTranslateX(holderPane.getTranslateX() + deltaX);
            holderPane.setTranslateY(holderPane.getTranslateY() + deltaY);
        }

        private void handleClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            if (!wasDragged && event.getClickCount() == 1) {
                switch (event.getButton()) {
                    case PRIMARY -> {
                        /*
                         * Convert coordinates to 'holderPane' space (takes into account all
                         * transformations). This only works because 'holderPane' is a direct
                         * child of the event source.
                         */
                        var location = holderPane.parentToLocal(event.getX(), event.getY());

                        var circle = new Circle(10);
                        circle.setCenterX(location.getX());
                        circle.setCenterY(location.getY());
                        holderPane.getChildren().add(circle);
                    }
                    case SECONDARY -> {
                        if (event.isAltDown()) {
                            holderPane.setTranslateX(0);
                            holderPane.setTranslateY(0);
                            holderPane.setScaleX(1);
                            holderPane.setScaleY(1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>**Note:** Code compiled and tested with Java 20.0.1 and JavaFX 20.0.1.</sup>